# Can the transpose of a matrix times itself reveal the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I only have $AA^T$ and I know that $A$ has the dimensions $m \times n$ where $m \gg n$, is there a way to get the matrix $A$?

Also, what if it was $A^TA$. Would I be able to get $A$ out of $A^TA$?

EDIT: What if A was formed of two sub-matrices $\left[\matrix{A_1 \\ A_2}\right]$ with $A_1$ has dimensions $m_1 \times n$ and $A_2$ has dimensions $m_2 \times n$, and in addition to $AA^T$, I also knew $A_2$. Would I be able to recover $A_1$? If so, what conditions should apply in terms of $m_1, m_2$ and $n$ (and other conditions) in order for the recovery of $A_1$ to happen?

Comment: what do you mean by m>>n?

Comment: Let $B=AQ$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix. Then $BB^T=AA^T$, so you cannot recover $A$ from $AA^T$. Similarly, if $C=RA$ where $R$ is orthogonal then $C^TC=A^TA$.

Comment: you can say $rank(A) = rank(AA^T)$

Comment: @Zero I mean that m is much greater than n

Comment: @Rahul Thanks a lot. Would you please take a look at my edit, and feel free to have your answer as formal answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @abel Thank. Would you please look at my edit.

Comment: you can approximate $A$ by smaller rank matrix by truncating the singular value decomposition of $A$ at a suitable place.

Comment: @abel would you please elaborate more on this. My knowledge is limited. How effective would this approximation be? Feel free to write a formal answer if you like. Thanks.

Comment: see the link http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89639

Comment: @abel Thanks a lot